# How to disable this app without google play services that i have disabled?

Tags: applications, google-play-services

Can somebody help me modify this app so it can work without Google play services? I tried lucky patcher, but it crashed with a message 'Unfortunately, NASA app has stopped'. It is an app called NASA, developed by NASA agency, National Aeronautics Space Agency. It can be found in Google play. I can't use Google play Services because it is deleted, and my phone can't support it. I must have really damaged the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access, try installing Google Play Services from apkmirror[dot]com . There are instructions available for choosing the right version. Then make it a system app.